# How to generate entity class without create table automatic

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I created some reports for my system, and that report is made up of many tables. For this, I create a Domain class with an @Entity annotation and implement a JpaRepository repository, I'm using the native query with @Query, as shown below.

My problem is that for each domain class a table is being created by hibernate, how do I stop it?

My Domain class:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@IdClass(WidgetDailyReportCompositeKey.class)
public class WidgetDailyReportDomain{

    @Id
    @Column(updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private UUID id_construction;

    @Id
    @Column(updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Date dt_cost;

    @Column(updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Double total;
}
```

My Repository:

```
public interface WidgetRepository extends JpaRepository<WidgetDailyReportDomain, UUID>{

    @Query(value =  "     SELECT ct.id AS id_construction,                                                                                              " +
                    "            ct.name,                                                                                                               " +
                    "            sm.dt_service AS dt_cost,                                                                                              " +
                    "            sum(smi.nu_value * stiv.amount) AS total                                                                               " +
                    "       FROM service_measurement sm                                                                                                 " +
                    " INNER JOIN service_measurement_item smi   ON smi.id_service_measurement = sm.id                                                   " +
                    " INNER JOIN service s                      ON s.id                       = sm.id_service                                           " +
                    " INNER JOIN service_type_item_service stiv ON stiv.id_service            = sm.id_service                                           " +
                    "                                          AND stiv.id_service_type_item = smi.id_service_item                                      " +
                    " INNER JOIN construction ct                ON ct.id                      = s.id_construction                                       " +
                    "      WHERE s.id_construction IN (                                                                                                 " +
                    "                                   select s.id_construction                                                                        " +
                    "                                   from service_measurement sm                                                                     " +
                    "                                   INNER JOIN service_measurement_item smi   ON smi.id_service_measurement = sm.id                 " +
                    "                                   INNER JOIN service s                      ON s.id                       = sm.id_service         " +
                    "                                   INNER JOIN service_type_item_service stiv ON stiv.id_service            = sm.id_service         " +
                    "                                                                            AND stiv.id_service_type_item  = smi.id_service_item   " +
                    "                                   INNER JOIN construction ct                on ct.id                      = s.id_construction     " +
                    "                                   WHERE sm.dt_service BETWEEN :minDate AND :maxDate                                               " +
                    "                                   GROUP BY s.id_construction                                                                      " +
                    "                                   ORDER BY sum(smi.nu_value * stiv.value) DESC                                                    " +
                    "                                   limit :limit                                                                                    " +
                    "       )                                                                                                                           " +
                    "       AND sm.dt_service BETWEEN :minDate AND :maxDate                                                                             " +
                    "  GROUP BY ct.id, sm.dt_service                                                                                                    " +
                    "    HAVING sum(smi.nu_value * stiv.amount) > 0                                                                                     " +
                    "  ORDER BY sm.dt_service;", nativeQuery = true)
    List<WidgetDailyReportDomain> findTopExpensiveConstruction(@Param("minDate") Date minDate, @Param("maxDate") Date maxDate, @Param("limit") int limit);

//....
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After @Zagarh answer, i did a lith of search about DTO, and i came up with a not very elegant solution, but that is working:

The Domain class :

```
public class WidgetDailyReportDomain{

    private UUID id_construction;
    private String name;
    private Date dt_cost;
    private Double total;

}
```

I have to create a custom result mapping, for the JPA be able of mapping de result, i use the annotation `@SqlResultSetMapping`. But for some reason she is only identify in a class that is annotated with `@ Entity`. For not to get disorganized, i create a class exclusive to annotation with `@ SqlResultSetMapping`, because i gona have a lot of mapping to do. The class looked like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "widget_daily_mapping",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = WidgetDailyReportDomain.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name="id_construction", type = UUID.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "name", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "dt_cost", type = Date.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "total", type = Double.class)
                        }

                )
        }
)
public abstract class ResultSetMappingConfig {
}
```

And then i create a custom implementation of Jpa Repository

```
public interface WidgetRepositoryCustom {
    List<WidgetDailyReportDomain> findTopExpensiveConstruction(Date minDate, Date maxDate, int limit);

}


@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class AR_serviceRepositoryImpl implements AR_serviceRepositoryCustom{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<AR_serviceDomain> getListOfService(UUID id_construction) {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("
          //Native Query Here...
        ", "widget_daily_mapping");// Put the result mapping Here
        query.setParameter(1, id_construction //..Parameters Here);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Ps: 1) If any one have a better solution please let me know. 2) Sorry for my english, i'm using google translate.

Answer (score 0):

Your WidgetDailyReportDomain is actually projection. You don't need to mark it as @Entity.
And your @Query could belong to any other really existing repository.

Comment: If i don't mark as @Entity for some rease the JPA is not able of mapping the UUID field, and throw a error: `No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111`

Comment: One possible workaround would be to build that UUID object on the constructor itself using a String value

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the `javax.persistence` annotations like `@Column`, `@Id`, `@Entity`. These annotations represent properties of a table, which you seem to not want it to be.

Then you can use the WidgetDailyReportDomain object as a DTO to be your projection and not have it attached to the EntityManager:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos

EDIT: Also, do not forget to build a constructor for that object so that Spring JPA loads the values into the object (like described on the documentation).
If you don't want to build a constructor, maybe you can change it into an interface and use it as your projection: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces

Comment: I was able of retrive data from the data base using DTO, but i have a problem, the JPARepository was not able to mappe the id as UUID. Even if i map with @type, i'm still get ```No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111```. I belive that is not possible use @type without @Entity

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Spring due to the `JpaRepository` in your question.

If you're using Spring Boot, then you can add

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

to your `application.yml` file, or

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

to your `application.properties` file.

If you're using a `persistence.xml` file, you could add a property to disable it there, too:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>
```

Disabling the generation of the schema tables like this means that you'll have to make sure they're created by some other means before your application will work, though.

Comment: That is what i wanted to do, work with flyway make easy a lot of thing, but all project
is depending of that, and i'm not able to change that

Comment: So, are you looking to disable the generation for *specific* entities only?

Comment: exactly! I came up with a not very elegant solution, I will post as an answer